# Unable to access "Advanced Permissions" settings

Tags: permissions, wss-3.0

I have a WSS3 server set up for development purposes but I am unable to access the `Advanced Permissions` in the `Users and Permissions` section of the Site Settings.
I'm trying to set up a test condition where users have write access to some lists and not others.

There are only two site owner accounts, the domain Administrator account and my own domain account. Which ever I log in with, I do not have permission to enter this part of the site.

As far as I can remember, I did set up this Sharepoint around 6 months a go now, there are no other accounts aside from a test visitor and test member. Is there a way I can check which user has access to this part of the Site Settings?

Since it didn't work from my computer I've been trying to access when logged into the actual server itself, producing the same results.

Comment: Are you sure you are Site Collection Administrator? An alternative would be to use Web Application Policies in Central Admin and give your accounts FULL CONTROL permissions for the Whole web application

Comment: I had forgotten about the Central Admin! I did have the `domain\Administrator` account set as the Site Collection administrator.
Got this sorted now thanks for the pointers @C.Marius!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my Site Collection Administrator was by looking here:
`Central Administration > Application Management > Site Collection Owners`

The reason I wasn't able to access the Advanced Permissions section was due to the web application settings in this section:
`Central Administration > Application Management > User Permissions for Web Application`

I checked the `Manage Web Site` box and saved the configuration, which allowed my account that was already Site Admin to get into the previously locked off section.